# The anchor is not working but it does have a not broken href

Tags: html

My anchor tag on github pages is not working it leads me to 8bitbug.com but i cant change anything in the settings or i cant find anything to change that the anchor tag does lead to the index file

```
<a class="Introduction" href="/index.html">Introduction</a>
```

The parent element is

```
<div class="Introduction">
```

The problem seems to be only on github since on vercel the anchor tag works completely fine

I tried to change the class the parent element

Answer (score 1):

You should add " `.` " to begining of your href like;

```
<a class="Introduction" href="./index.html">
```

It will work if the index.html file is in the same folder.

If you want to move up to parent directories you can use " `../` " for every directory.

```
<a class="Introduction" href="../index.html">
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your anchor tag is in root directory you can modify it like this:-

```
<a class="Introduction" href="index.html">Introduction</a>
```

If the same issue occurs again then you should check your GitHub Pages settings for the correct base URL.

Answer (score -1):

```
<a class="Introduction" href="/index.html">Introduction</a>
```

This code is correct but forward slash is not used in filename. So rename the file name to index.html and it will only work if the file index.html is in the same folder...

Comment: The `/` is the path where to search for that file, like in `/folder/file.ext`, but in this case in the root of the server ("//www.host.tld/index.html")